# Xamarin Mono Android wrong references to HttpClient

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient

Every time I debug my hybrid app, I get the following error:

> I/mono-stdout(  724): Xamarin.Android returned no custom HttpClientHandler.
>   Defaulting to System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler

I have a reference to System.Net.Http, but somehow it tries to find another one. I expect that this might be the reason the app sometimes stops working.

Anybody know how to solve this in C# 4.5?
Does anybody know why Xamarin is updating their development in VS so much?

Comment: There was someone came up with the same error [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73314/xamarin-android-returned-no-custom-httpclienthandler). But ends up with net connection problem. Could you try disable the windows firewall and make sure you have a successful connection to your destination address?

Comment: Well it returns the value alright so not my problem that its not returning, as it does it just switches to another Net.Http. I read somewhere in Xamarin that there is some Net.Http in Mono.Android but I cant find it.